# Is there an API in dfuse that's like `get_table_by_scope` in chain API?

Tags: dfuse

Is there an API in dfuse that's like `get_table_by_scope` in chain API?

I have a dapp that needs table snapshots of contracts, and it needs to have all of  the tables' scope at any block height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's something that we have on our radar but nothing is available yet inside the dfuse API to retrieve the list of scopes of have a given table at any block height.